# Error during mavros Multi-Vehicle Simulation with px4 in Gazebo | Invalid <param> tag

Tags: ros, px4

I followed the instruction as mentioned [here](https://dev.px4.io/en/simulation/multi-vehicle-simulation.html). Everything worked fine but at last stage when I try to run:-

```
roslaunch px4 multi_uav_mavros_sitl.launch
```

I get following:-

```
... logging to /home/yograj/.ros/log/40d4394e-0a3d-11e8-a1f1-3c77e68de09b/roslaunch-yograj-Inspiron-5537-12334.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Usage: xacro.py [options] <input>

xacro.py: error: expected exactly one input file as argument
while processing /home/yograj/src/Firmware/launch/single_vehcile_spawn.launch:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [iris_1_sdf]: command [/opt/ros/kinetic/share/xacro/xacro.py /home/yograj/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo/models/rotors_description/urdf/iris_base.xacro rotors_description_dir:=/home/yograj/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo/models/rotors_description mavlink_udp_port:=14560 > iris_1.urdf ; 'gz sdf -p iris_1.urdf'] returned with code [2]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(arg cmd)" name="$(arg vehicle)_$(arg ID)_sdf"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Launch file

```
<launch>

    <!-- Posix SITL environment launch script -->
    <arg name="x" default="0"/>
    <arg name="y" default="0"/>
    <arg name="z" default="0"/>
    <arg name="R" default="0"/>
    <arg name="P" default="0"/>
    <arg name="Y" default="0"/>
    <arg name="est" default="ekf2"/>
    <arg name="vehicle" default="iris"/>
    <arg name="ID" default="1"/>
    <arg name="rcS" default="$(find px4)/posix-configs/SITL/init/$(arg est)/$(arg vehicle)_$(arg ID)"/>
    <arg name="mavlink_udp_port" default="14560" />


    <arg name="cmd" default="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find px4)/Tools/sitl_gazebo/models/rotors_description/urdf/$(arg vehicle)_base.xacro rotors_description_dir:=$(find px4)/Tools/sitl_gazebo/models/rotors_description mavlink_udp_port:=$(arg mavlink_udp_port) > $(arg vehicle)_$(arg ID).urdf ; 'gz sdf -p $(arg vehicle)_$(arg ID).urdf'" />


    <param command="$(arg cmd)" name="$(arg vehicle)_$(arg ID)_sdf" />

    <node name="sitl_$(arg ID)" pkg="px4" type="px4" output="screen"
        args="$(find px4) $(arg rcS)">
    </node>

    <node name="$(arg vehicle)_$(arg ID)_spawn" output="screen" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
        args="-sdf -param $(arg vehicle)_$(arg ID)_sdf -model $(arg vehicle)_$(arg ID) -x $(arg x) -y $(arg y) -z $(arg z) -R $(arg R) -P $(arg P) -Y $(arg Y)" respawn="false"/>


</launch>

<!-- vim: set et ft=xml fenc=utf-8 ff=unix sts=0 sw=4 ts=4 : -->
```

Comment: Your launch file seems incorrect. Either that or you don't have the urdf file you are trying to load. As said in the error log, xacro needs on input file but did not get it. Can you post your launch file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using old version of px4 firmware. There was some problem with launch file (single_vehcile_spawn.launch). Correcting

```
 <arg name="cmd" default="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find px4)/Tools/sitl_gazebo/models/rotors_description/urdf/$(arg vehicle)_base.xacro rotors_description_dir:=$(find px4)/Tools/sitl_gazebo/models/rotors_description mavlink_udp_port:=$(arg mavlink_udp_port) > $(arg vehicle)_$(arg ID).urdf ; 'gz sdf -p $(arg vehicle)_$(arg ID).urdf'" />
```

in single_vehcile_spawn.launch with

```
<arg name="cmd" default="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find px4)/Tools/sitl_gazebo/models/rotors_description/urdf/$(arg vehicle)_base.xacro rotors_description_dir:=$(find px4)/Tools/sitl_gazebo/models/rotors_description mavlink_udp_port:=$(arg mavlink_udp_port)" />
```